# What is the difference between base-, array- and cursor-adapter

Tags: android

Should I use array adapter or base adapter or cursor adapter? 
What do you use most? I found some code that uses base adapter for fragments. Can I use array adapter or cursoradapter for listfragments?

I know how to use listview in a simple way like using the android.r.simple. I want to know what I should use in creating a listview that uses listfragment and populating it with data that came from SQLite.

What is the easiest adapter to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are difference between the different adapter class. You should decide to use one depending on your model data.

- ArrayAdapter is better if you have an ArrayList of objects.
- CursorAdapter is better if you have a database query and a Cursor
- BaseAdapter is the most customizable, so you can use it for anything (you have to customize it a little bit more than others)

Comment: Does that mean that a beginner should use arrayadapter then cursor adapter then base adapter?

Comment: No. They are not sequentially ordered by developer skills. If you have, for example, a listview to populate with a simple list of string s, then there is no reason to not use an ArrayAdapter, because it is the fastest solution you can take.

Comment: how about fragments and database? What do you always use?? Im having a hard time in base adapter.. SO i want to know other alternative aside from using that.. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I normally end up extending BaseAdapter.  It's simple enough, and ArrayAdapter isn't flexible enough to handle the case where items have multiple values that need to go into different fields in your list item.

Comment: how about cursor adpater?? do use it??